# Why my thread is not working?

Tags: java, swing

Why is my thread is not working?

I want to show a message on `JFrame` for a short time ..then I want to close the message and start my main `JPanel`.

Should I put the thread outside my main class?

I searched on Google about more..but I am hopeless.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SwitchCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JFrame JF = new JFrame("SwitchJpanel");
        JF.setSize(300, 200);
        JF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Thread Cl = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JPanel P = new JPanel(null);
                    JF.getContentPane().add(P);
                    JButton L = new JButton("Wellcome");
                    L.setBounds(20, 30, 100, 20);
                    P.add(L);
                    sleep(10000000);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };
        Cl.start();
        JF.getContentPane().removeAll();
        JF.getContentPane().revalidate();
        final JPanel P1 = new JPanel(null);
        JF.getContentPane().add(P1);
        JLabel L1 = new JLabel("Left");
        L1.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 20);
        P1.add(L1);
        JLabel L2 = new JLabel("Right");
        L2.setBounds(120, 20, 100, 20);
        P1.add(L2);
        final JButton B1 = new JButton("Panel1");
        B1.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 20);
        P1.add(B1);
        final JButton B2 = new JButton("Panel2");
        B2.setBounds(120, 60, 100, 20);
        P1.add(B2);
        B1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JF.getContentPane().removeAll();
                JPanel P1 = new JPanel(null);
                JF.getContentPane().add(P1);
                JF.getContentPane().revalidate();
                JLabel L1 = new JLabel("Left");
                L1.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 20);
                P1.add(L1);
                JLabel L2 = new JLabel("Right");
                L2.setBounds(120, 20, 100, 20);
                P1.add(L2);
                B1.setText("Panel1");
                B1.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 20);
                P1.add(B1);
                B2.setText("Panel2");
                B2.setBounds(120, 60, 100, 20);
                P1.add(B2);
            }

        });
        B2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JF.getContentPane().removeAll();
                JPanel P2 = new JPanel(null);
                JF.getContentPane().add(P2);
                JF.getContentPane().revalidate();

                JLabel L3 = new JLabel("UP");
                L3.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 20);
                P2.add(L3);
                JLabel L4 = new JLabel("Down");
                L4.setBounds(120, 20, 100, 20);
                P2.add(L4);
                B1.setText("Panel3");
                B1.setBounds(20, 60, 100, 20);
                P2.add(B1);
                B2.setText("Panel4");
                B2.setBounds(120, 60, 100, 20);
                P2.add(B2);

            }

        });
        JF.setResizable(false);
        JF.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your code:

1. You're executing all your code in `main` method.
2. You're not following the [Oracle naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) where variable names should be in lowerCamelCase
3. You're setting all your components bounds manually, while this might seem like the best and easiest way to make a complex GUI when starting to learn Swing, this isn't the correct way, instead make use of a [Layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or combinations of them as well as [Empty borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) if needed for spacing, Swing has to work in multiple screen sizes, PLAFs and resolutions.
4. > I want to show a message on JFrame for a short time ..then I want to close the message and start my main JPanel.

   It seems like what you want to do is use a [Dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) with an [auto close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306868/can-i-set-a-timer-on-a-java-swing-jdialog-box-to-close-after-a-number-of-millise) after some time has passed
5. From the above point, you don't want to use a `Thread` but a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

   `Thread.sleep(...)` will make your program to "freeze" until it finishes, while a `Timer` will execute in its own thread.
6. You're not placing your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Comment: Thank you.. I didnt know about swing timer.. i use it now and works :) wow